# Move existing jointplot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, jointplot

I tried answers from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238041/move-and-resize-legends-box-in-matplotlib) to no avail in Matplotlib 1.5.1.

I have a seaborn figure:

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip",  data = tips[["total_bill", "tip"]].applymap(lambda x : -np.log10(x)))
```

This does not work:

```
g.ax_joint.legend(loc = 'lower right')
```

As well as this:

```
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=4, borderaxespad=0.)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:520: UserWarning: No labelled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.
  warnings.warn("No labelled objects found. "
```

What is the way to locate an existing legend to lower right in this case?

---

Not an elegant solution for now is:

```
ll = g.ax_joint.get_legend().get_texts()[0]._text
g.ax_joint.get_legend().remove()
g.ax_joint.text( -12, -12, ll,  fontsize=14)
```

However, I believe there should be a better way.

Comment: There are some examples on the MatPlotLib docs page, http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html

Comment: There are examples, but for example ` loc=4`  has no effec in my case if I do not provide handles to artists. And in case of seaborn I was not able to find the handles I need. If you know how to get them, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy (using strings like `'lower right'`) way to relocate an existing legend that I am aware of.

To get the handles of an existing legend you can use `legend.legendHandles()`. For the labels, `legend.get_texts()` will give you the `Text` objects. In order to retrieve the actual labels you'd better use `.get_text()` instead of the private attribute `_text`.

The following will copy the handles and labels of an existing legend to a new one. Other properties of the legend won't be copied.

```
legend = g.ax_joint.get_legend()
labels = (x.get_text() for x in legend.get_texts())
g.ax_joint.legend(legend.legendHandles, labels, loc='lower right')
```

I previously suggested using `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` but this will search in the axes, not the legend, and is not useful in this case.

Comment: This unfortunately has an effect but not a meaningful one: the `handles` and `labels` returned are empty and the second operation removes legend from figure.  This fact that the handles are empty is quite strange as `ll = g.ax_joint.get_legend().get_texts()[0]._text` does return the displayed text. Please see a complete testable example above.

Comment: @DinaLituiev You're right, sir, `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` won't work in your case. I had issues with the `load_dataset` call and had to test with a made up example that misled me. See my edit.