# Moving a Pandas Legend causes labels to changes from patches to lines

Tags: python, pandas, legend

I'm moving a `Pandas` legend but trying to keep it as patches. It swaps to lines when I try to adjust the parameters - *is there a setting I'm missing to stop this happening or am I resetting the legend or something by accident?* What am I doing wrong?

The code is a bit complicated so I'm putting in the useful bits. Don't worry about bad formatting, I just skipped out a load of formatting lines to make it simpler to understand.

Simplified code:

```
my_colors = list(['goldenrod', 'royalblue', 'darkviolet', 'firebrick'])

#set up subplots
fig_heatprop, axes_heatprop = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios':[8, 1]})

#make totales percentages
df_touse_perc = df_touse.divide(df_touse.sum(axis=1), axis=0).multiply(100)

ax = df_touse_perc.plot(kind='area', stacked=True, color=my_colors, ax=axes_heatprop[0]) #.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, -0.3), ncol=2)
```

does this:
[image]

**but if I try to move the legend, it swaps it from patches to lines**

```
#move legend
ax.legend(loc=9, bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, -0.2), ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move existing legend in Matplotlib 1.5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562515/move-existing-legend-in-matplotlib-1-5-1)

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate to me. I am trying to retain the patches style of legend after moving it. I can create and move it fine

Comment: That's exactly what the accepted answer to that question does: it keeps the labels and handles (in your case patches) of the original legend without you having to manually recreate them.

Comment: Thanks @Goyo , sorry I didn't read it correctly apparently. I will try that way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the default legend by setting the attribute `legend` to `False` in the last line of your main code block

```
ax = df_touse_perc.plot(kind='area', 
                        stacked=True, 
                        color=my_colors, 
                        ax=axes_heatprop[0],
                        legend=False)
```

For the patches you could create a patch per colour and have a list of them and finally you can set the legend using the line you mentioned alongside setting the `handles` attribute to the list of patches created

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
patch =[]
for c,l in zip(my_colors,df_touse_perc.columns.tolist()):
     patch.append(mpatches.Patch(color=c, label=l))

ax.legend(handles=patch,loc=9, bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, -0.2), ncol=2)
```

Comment: The OP wants the patches.

Comment: OK, I've added a roughly thought suggestion, Thanks!

Comment: I was hoping there was some setting to change to stop it resetting it to lines instead of patches but this is a good enough work around. Thanks! Additions: You dropped a closing bracket on the `patch.append` line and I used `list(df_touse_perc)` instead of `my_lables` to get an automatic list of the labels from the dataframe column headings