# 'best' location for legend is covering text

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am adding some text to my plot (always in the left top corner), and when I add legend with `loc='best'` it seems to ignore the text.

Code to reproduce the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2]
plt.plot(x, x, label='plot name')
plt.gca().text(0.05, 0.95, 'some text', transform=plt.gca().transAxes, verticalalignment='top')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

The result I get:

[image]

My text is always in the same place, so if I can exclude 'upper left' from `best` options it will work as well. But curious why the algorithm of `loc` ignores it.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move and resize legends-box in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238041/move-and-resize-legends-box-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Thanks @felixk. It doesn't answer my question. The answer suggests moving it "by hand". I am having many plots. In all of them the text in the same place, but 'best' location might differ from one to another. I wish to make the loc='best' algorithm somehow understand the text is there, or tell it implicitly to avoid using 'upper left' and look for other best options.

Comment: You might draw some dummy line at the spot of the text, e.g. `plt.plot(0.05, 0.95, transform=plt.gca().transAxes, color='none')`.

Comment: You might want to open an issue on [github ](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib)

Comment: @JohanC that's a nice work around! It works well. I leave it open maybe for a 'proper' solution.

Comment: I've run into situations where after adding an element/artist the Axes *doesn't know* it is there and messes up other positioning . I want to recall that I decided that sometimes order mattered and that the Axes needed to be *drawn* or rendered after manual additions for it to account for all previously added elements/artist. Sorry but I don't have it installed on this machine.  What happens if you swap the order of `plt.plot...` and `plt.gca.text...`.  Does it make a difference if you work directly with the Axes (like shown in most Matplotlib examples) instead of using pyplot?

Comment: This is definitely the behaviour of `legend('best')`.  You can file a bug report or feature request, or use a workaround as suggested by @JohanC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if people still interested, but I encountered the same  here is another work around:

You can use the `bbox_to_anchor` to limit the legend's free searching space. Of course to use that you need to know roughly where your text will be in advance.

For your code, change the `legend` line to `plt.gca().legend(loc='best',  bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0, 1, 0.9))` (limit the legend to only the lower 90% of the vertical space).

Full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2]
plt.plot(x, x, label='plot name')
plt.gca().text(0.05, 0.95, 'some text', transform=plt.gca().transAxes, verticalalignment='top')
plt.gca().legend(loc='best',  bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0, 1, 0.9))
plt.show()
```

BTW, I opened an issue at [github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/23323)

Comment: This looks like a fine workaround as well. And you opened a bug for that (lazy me, I didn't). I will give you the answer for that one :)